# Getting an error with Python's cx_oracle callproc function

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I have this code:

```
        curs.callproc('add_command_pkg.add_command', [],
                      { 'command_id' : 7,
                        'session_id' : None,
                        'expiry_time' : 'sysdate + 7',
                        'config_id' : 6 })
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> File "N:\app\MainWidget.py", line 453, in myFunc
>       curs.callproc('add_command_pkg.add_command', [], { 'command_id' : 7,
>   'session_id' : None, 'expiry
>   _time' : 'sysdate + 7', 'config_id' : 6 })
>   cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a nu
>   meric was expected
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

What parameter am I passing in wrong and how do I fix it?

edit:

command signature:

```
                                        ( command_id   IN NUMBER,
                                          expiry_time  IN DATE,
                                          session_id   IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                          config_id    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
                                        );
```

Also, how do I commit this?

Comment: What's the signature of the "add_command_pkg.add_command" ?

Comment: @Gerrat, what does that mean?

Comment: Basically the first line of the function:  e.g. something like: procedure add_command (param1 in number, param2 in varchar2)

Comment: @Gerrat o ok, I added it in the OP as an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass in the string 'sysdate + 7' for parameter expiry_time.

You could compose a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) object or perhaps just change your procedure to accept a numeric "days offset" and add or subtract that from sysdate within the procedure itself.

For the committing, you can call [commit](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/connection.html#Connection.commit) on cx_Oracle's connection object.